# Find connected rectangles from a HashSet using java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a HashSet filled with custom rectangle object("name",center_X,center_Y, width, height). i wrote a method to find if two rectangles are connected(touch/intersect). But i want to get all the rectangles that are a group. For example: if rectA is connected with rectB, RectC is connected with rectB but not rectA directly they all are connected because rectB is common.

I can find the shapes that have direct connection. But I want to get the group where shapes with secondary connection is also included. I'd assume recursion is useful in this case but can't solve it yet. Any solution/suggestion?

```
public static void canItbeGroup(HashSet<RECTANGLE> ipRectangles)
{
    Deque<RECTANGLE> ipDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(ipRectangles);

    for (RECTANGLE currRectangle : ipDeque)
    {
        Set<String> tempGrpMbrShapeID = new HashSet<>();
        RECTANGLE tempRect = ipDeque.pop();
        for (RECTANGLE r : ipDeque)
        {
            if (tempRect.areShapesFriend(r))
            {
                tempGrpMbrShapeID.add(r.shapeID);
                tempGrpMbrShapeID.add(tempRect.shapeID);
            }
        }
        if (tempGrpMbrShapeID.size() > 1)
        {
            System.out.println(tempGrpMbrShapeID);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    HashSet<RECTANGLE> rectHS = new HashSet<>();

    RECTANGLE aRect = new RECTANGLE("a", 3, 2, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE aInnerRect = new RECTANGLE("aIn", 3, 2, 1, 1);
    RECTANGLE bRect = new RECTANGLE("b", 5, 3, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE cRect = new RECTANGLE("c", 7, 3, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE dRect = new RECTANGLE("d", 4, 5, 4, 2);
    RECTANGLE eRect = new RECTANGLE("e", 11, 3, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE fRect = new RECTANGLE("f", 11, 6, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE gRect = new RECTANGLE("g", 13, 3, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE hRect = new RECTANGLE("h", 4, 8, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE iRect = new RECTANGLE("i", 14, 1, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE jRect = new RECTANGLE("j", 16, 7, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE kRect = new RECTANGLE("k", 15, 6, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE lRect = new RECTANGLE("l", 8, 8, 2, 2);
    RECTANGLE mRect = new RECTANGLE("m", 5, 10, 2, 2);


    rectHS.add(aRect);
    rectHS.add(bRect);
    rectHS.add(cRect);
    rectHS.add(eRect);
    rectHS.add(dRect);
    rectHS.add(fRect);
    rectHS.add(gRect);
    rectHS.add(aInnerRect);
    rectHS.add(hRect);
    rectHS.add(iRect);
    rectHS.add(jRect);
    rectHS.add(kRect);
    rectHS.add(lRect);
    rectDQ.add(aRect);
    rectDQ.add(bRect);
    rectDQ.add(cRect);
    rectDQ.add(dRect);
    rectDQ.add(eRect);

    canItbeGroup(rectHS);
}
```

output i get:

```
[a, b, aIn],[b, c, d],[g, i],[e, g],[j, k],[c, d]
```

I'll need the group as

```
[a,b,aIn,c,d], [e,g,i], [j,k]
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't solve the problem for you, but I will give you a general approach.

1. Generate an initial `Collection<Set<String>>`. This is effectively what you've already done, but you'll need to store them so that you can merge the sets, rather than printing the group as soon as your find them
2. Iterate over all groups (`i`), and compare each group to every other group (`j`)
3. If the `i` contains any item of `j` then merge the sets (put all items of `j` into `i`, and remove all items from `j`)
4. Go back to 2 and repeat until you perform 1 full iteration where no merges occur.
5. Iterate again and remove any empty sets.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. But can you suggest any solution using recursion. I am new to recursion.